# c code: fprintf print on file less times than expected

Tags: c, file, for-loop, printf, buffer

I ran 10 copy of the same code (changing only some parameters) simultaneously in 10 different folder (each program working in single core). 
In each program I have a for loop (the number of iterations, NumSamples, can be  50000, 500000 or 5000000 (the number of iteration depend on the specific time of execution of a single iteration; A greater number of iteration are performed in quicker cases )). Inside each iteration I compute a certain quantity (a double variable) and then save it on file with (inside the for block): 
`fprintf(fp_TreeEv, "%f\n", TreeEv);`
where TreeEv is the name of the variable computed at each cycle.
To be sure that the code save the variable right after the fprintf command I set the buffer to 0 after the file opening, with:

`TreeEv=fopen("data.txt", "a");`  
 `setbuf(TreeEv, NULL);`
The program ends without error. Also I know that all the NumSamples iterations have been done during the execution (I print a variable initialized with 0 at the beginning of the for loop and that increase by one at each cycle).
When I open the txt file, at the ending of code execution I see that inside the file there are less row (data) than expected (NumSamples), for example 4996187 instead of 5000000
(I've also checked that csv file miss the same amount of data with `tr -d -c , < filename.csv | wc -c`, as suggested by Barmar)
What could be the source of the problem?

I copy below the for loop of my code(inv_trasf is just a function that generate random numbers):\

```
    char NomeFiletxt [64];
    char NomeFilecsv [64];
    sprintf(NomeFilecsv, "TreeEV%d.csv", N);
    sprintf(NomeFiletxt, "TreeEVCol%d.txt", N);
    FILE* fp_TreeEv;
    fp_TreeEv=fopen(NomeFilecsv, "a");
    FILE* fp_TreeEvCol;
    fp_TreeEvCol=fopen(NomeFiletxt, "a");
    setbuf(fp_TreeEv, NULL);
    setbuf(fp_TreeEvCol, NULL);

    for(ciclo=0; ciclo<NumSamples; ciclo++){

        sum = 0;
        sum_2=0;
        k_max_int=0;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
            deg_seq[i]=inv_trasf(k_max_double_round); 
            sum+=deg_seq[i];
            sum_2+=(deg_seq[i]*deg_seq[i]);

            if(deg_seq[i]>k_max_int){
                k_max_int = deg_seq[i];
            }   
        }


        if((sum%2)!=0){
            do{
                v=rand_int(N);
            }while(deg_seq[v]==k_max_int);
            deg_seq[v]++;
            sum++;
            sum_2+=(deg_seq[v]*deg_seq[v]-(deg_seq[v]-1)*(deg_seq[v])-1);

        }
        TreeEV = ((double)sum_2/sum)-1.;
        fprintf(fp_TreeEv, "%f,", TreeEV);
        fprintf(fp_TreeEvCol, "%f\n", TreeEV);



    CycleCount +=1;
    }
    fclose(fp_TreeEv);
    fclose(fp_TreeEvCol);
```

**Could the problem stay in the ssd that, in a given moment, failed to follow the codes and wasn't able to call back data (for the presence of Null buffer)?** 
Only codes with greater execution time (on the single cycle iteration) save correctly all the expected data. From `man setbuf` "If the argument buf is NULL, only the mode is affected; a new buffer will be allocated on the next read or write operation."

[**EDIT**]
I noticed that inside one of the txt file "corrupted" there is one invalid value:
[image: cutted sequence of printed values inside one of txt corrupted files]

I checked that it is the only value with a different number of digit; to do so I first removed all the "." from the txt file with `tr -d \. < TreeEVCol102400.txt > test.txt` and then sorted the new file with `sort -g test.txt > t.dat`. After that is easy to check at the top/end of t.dat file for values with more/less digit.
I've also checked that it is the only value in the file with at least 2 "." with:
`grep -ni '\.*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.' TreeEVCol102400.txt`
I checked that each corrupted files has just one invalid values of this kind.

Comment: You need to post the code.

Comment: Ok Barmar; the complete code is long, i extract the part around the problem

Comment: Do you actually close the file?

Comment: Just add enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @MartinJames That shouldn't matter if buffering is disabled.

Comment: @Barmar I am not convinced that buffering is disabled.  Buffering in the C runtime may well be disabled, but that is not the end of the story with I/O.  I'm sure that the OP has tried closing the file, (since that is an obvious thing to try), but just to be sure...'Do you actually close the file?'

Comment: @MartinJames Buffering in the OS controls whether it actually gets to the disk hardware, but that's transparent to applications. And even closing the file doesn't force it to disk, you have to call `fsync()`.

Comment: Anyway, the posted code does close the file.

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause the file to have fewer lines than expected. Does this happen in both the CSV and text files?

Comment: You could check the value returned by each `fprintf` call

Comment: @Barmar *Buffering in the OS controls whether it actually gets to the disk hardware, but that's transparent to applications.* Well, it's ***supposed*** to be.  Work in AWS some time.  There are times where it takes several seconds for data to be visible in files - even on non-shared file systems on a single virtual machine.  It sure was a nice "WTF?!?!" moment when I figured that out.

Comment: @user1172131 Are you running multiple threads or multiple processes?  `fprintf()` is not guaranteed to perform atomic append operations to the file it's writing to.

Comment: You can open the CSV file in any text editor. Please check the number of lines.

Comment: @user1172131 `tr -d -c , < filename.csv | wc -c` will tell you how many commas are in the CSV file

Comment: The csv files has the same number of values stored. I ran 10 time the code simultaneously (each one working in single core). Only codes with greater execution time (on the single cycle iteration) save correctly all the expected. From ```man setbuf``` "If the argument buf is NULL, only the mode is affected; a new buffer will be allocated on the next read or write operation." Now I'll do some tries to better understand where is the problem, and how the buffer works in my case

Comment: Andrew Henle, I was running multiples code; each code was writing on different files. Is it safe to do so? If, instead, I write with multiple codes on the same file may I have some problem for not being guaranteed to perform atomic append operations to the file it's writing to?

Answer (score 1):

When you set 'unbuffered' mode on a FILE, each character might<sup>1</sup> be written individually to the underlying device/file.  In that case, if mulitple processes are appending to the same file, if both try to write a number at the same time, they might get their digits interleaved, as you show with your "corrupted" value.  So setting _IONBF mode on a file is generally not what you want.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It's actually not possible to completely unbuffer a file -- there will still be disk buffers involved in the OS, and may still be a (small) stdio buffer to deal with some corner cases.  But in general, every character might be individually writte to a file.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer Chris Dodd. "*if mulitple processes are appending to the same file, if both try to write a number at the same time, they might get their digits interleaved, as you show with your "corrupted" value.*" The strange thing is that in the case above each code was appending on a different file. Is it possible that, the same phenomena you described, happens also with simultaneusly running codes, each writing on its own file?

Comment: @user1172131 if that happens, your filesystem is broken:)