# Missing data printed on file setting a NULL buffer

Tags: c, printf, buffer, disk, file-writing

I've already posted a question which describe my specific problem ([c code: fprintf print on file less times than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305027/c-code-fprintf-print-on-file-less-times-than-expected)) but here I'd like to approach the problem in more general form to understand some general mechanisms of the no buffering situation and the disk writing operation done in the `fprintf()` call.
Consider the following situation:
I have more indipendents codes running, each one in a different folder; each code has a for loop; in each iteration it draws a random number and print it in a file (one different file for each code):

```
#define N 10000000
int main(){
    FILE* fp_Data;
    fp_Data=fopen("Data.txt", "a");
    setbuf(fp_Data, NULL);

    srand48(time(NULL));

    int i;
    double u;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        u = drand48();
        fprintf(fp_Data, "%f\n", u);
    }
    fclose(fp_Data);

}
```

The above code is just a "toy model" to express my doubt:
**Is it possible that, in a given moment, during the execution, the ssd fails to follow the codes and isn't able to call back data (for the presence of Null buffer)?**

Comment: If that would happen, you should get an error, which you would have to check.

Comment: Is it possible to don't get any error ,from terminal, during the execution, if that happens?

Comment: Error checking and handling isn't automatic, you have to do it yourself explicitly in your program. For example check what `fprintf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Return_value).

Comment: Some programmer dude, yours is a good advice and from now on I will insert if condition after fprintf call to figure out when/if it return a negative int value. However I'd like to understand what are, in principle, the risk; this helps in the debug/error check to understand which could be the possible sources of error in that given situation